# Handlebars.js Partial Sub-Template generation

Tags: javascript, html, templating, handlebars.js

I am having issue with the Partials/Sub Template generation in the Handlebars.js.

I have used the registerPartials Method properly, but still it is giving some sort of issue in rendering. If I remove the partial template it would render the content properly.

Below is the code that I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Handlebars.js example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="placeholder">This will get replaced by handlebars.js</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="handlebars.js"></script>

    <script id="myTemplate" type="x-handlebars-template">
   {{#each allShoes}}
   <li>
   <span> {{name}} - </span> price: {{price}}
   {{> description}}
   </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>




    <script id="shoe-description" type="x-handlebars-template">
<ul>
    <li>{{color}}</li>
    <li>{{size}}</li>
</ul>
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var source = document.getElementById("myTemplate").innerHTML;
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

        // Register the Partial
        //Handlebars.registerPartial("description", $("#shoe-description").html());

       var shoesData = {
                            allShoes:[
                                        {name:"Nike", price:199.00,color:"black", size:10}, 
                                        {name:"Loafers", price:59.00, color:"blue", size:9}, 
                                        {name:"Wing Tip", price:259.00, color:"brown", size:11}
                                        ]
                            };

        Handlebars.registerPartial("description", $("#shoe-description").html());
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = template(shoesData);


    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Is there any issue with the registerPartial?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Ankit Tanna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that your rendering issues are a side effect of asking the browser to render invalid HTML. Your HTML ends up with, more or less, this structure:

```
<div>
    <li>
        <ul>...</ul>
    </li>
    ...
</div>
```

But an `<li>` **must** have a `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>` as its parent. I quote the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context):

> **Permitted parent elements**
>
> ul, ol, menu

So having a `<div>` as the parent of an `<li>` is invalid and the browser may rewrite your not-quite-HTML to make it valid HTML. That correction could be making a mess of your inner lists. Fix your HTML and try again:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="x-handlebars-template">
    <ul>
        {{#each allShoes}}
            ...
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/R23Ak/

Comment: Thanks a lot MU.But HTML generally renders the content right? You are Awesome with handlebars.js :)

Comment: The issue is, the same thing is not working in the Dreamweaver CC product Live View. Dont know why! will try to import the Handlebars lib that you are using. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Sorry, the issue was the jQuery file I am using got corrupted. Its a default import just as checking the box in jsfiddle. But it didnt work in my case. :) Now its working.